# Haskell -- Is there a monad sequence function for tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples, sequence, monads

Suppose I have a value of type `Monad m => (m a, m a)`, and I want to "sequence" the pair to create a value of type `Monad m => m (a, a)` that combines the monadic context of the two values in the same way the "sequence" function does. Is there some standard function or standard way of doing this? And does this operation even make sense?

Comment: I suppose the most natural approach would be
   sequence' (ma,mb) = (x,y)
       where x = head l
             y = last l
             l = sequence [ma, mb], just treating the tuple as a list of length 2?

Comment: @C.Quilley Use backticks to include inline code in comments `\`some code\``. Also, it's much easier if you use the `;` to separate definitions: `sequence' (ma, mb) = (x, y) where x=head L; y= last L; L = sequence [ma, mb]`

Comment: `uncurry $ liftM2 (,) :: Monad m => (m a1, m a2) -> m (a1, a2)` You can also do it with applicatives.  I wonder if there are mono-traversable instances for homogenous tuples up to some size.

Comment: I would say two things. First: this is strikes me as being simple and uncommon enough that there wouldn't be a library function for it; you can just do it online as Boyd suggests. Second: if such a function were to exist, you'd want to file it under `Applicative`, and it'd be something like  `(<,>) :: Applicative f -> f a -> f b -> f (a, b)`. This function is not a standard one, but you often find people talking about it because the associativity law that `Applicative` instances must obey is basically `a <,> (b <,> c) == (a <,> b) <,> c` (up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There wouldn't be a single function for all the different tuple types, since it wouldn't have a single type.

You could define a family of functions like:

```
ts0 = return
ts2 = uncurry $ liftM2 (,)
ts3 = uncurr3 $ liftM3 (,,)
{- ... -}
uncurr3 f (x, y, z) = f x y z
```

Of course, sequence in general is better applied to applicatives instead of monads, which is why it is part of the Traversable typeclass.  It would be possible to make homogenous tuples [(a,a,a) but not (a,b,a)] an instance of MonoTraversable, I believe.

You should also see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920139/2008899) which indicates there is already a library containing this family of functions.

Comment: Looking at the [`MonoTraversable` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.6.0.4/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html), I see there aren't any such instances, *and* the `MonoFunctor` and `Element` instances for `(a,b)` do the wrong thing (ignoring the first element) to be compatible with it.

Comment: Well, the Element instance isn't really a problem.  That MonoFunctor instance is a pain, but I think OverlappingInstances should work as (a,a) is a more specific type than (a,b).

Comment: You can also generalize this to `Applicative` with `liftA2`.

Answer (score 11):

```
ghci> import Control.Lens
ghci> sequenceOf both (getLine, getLine)
Apples
Bananas
("Apples","Bananas")
```

Comment: You just beat me there, except I was going to say the more general `each` instead of `both`. (It's the [example for sequenceOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:sequenceOf).

Comment: Using Lens in this case feels like using dynamite to clear out pigeons; fireworks will do just as well.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. True, but `lens` *does* tend to have tuple versions of several things the standard libraries only do for lists or at best uniform structures.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. Oh hm scratch the uniform, `each` requires the tuple elements to be the same type. In that respect your answer is better.

Comment: I personally like to use `each` as a `mapM` that is type safe in the arity (and less verbose than multiple lines of monadic actions for the arguments).

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. True, but if there are lots of simple explanations of how to use dynamite knocking around, the general population will get better at it. (I think that the analogy breaks down a little in the sense that I don't advocate the general population using TNT and prefer that caution were exercised with fireworks.)

Comment: @AndrewC I'm not sure I agree that lens is a easily approachable library; even having written quite a bit of Haskell, it took a moment before I could find what I needed an compose things out of the parts lens provides.  I think that Traversable is more accessible; my ideas around MonoTraversable were speculation, they weren't intended to be pedantic.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. I totally agree with you that lens is far from easy. However, I'm suggesting that simple bitesize examples like this could make it easier to learn.

Answer (score 9):

The [tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) package has `Data.Tuple.Sequence.sequenceT` which is overloaded for up to 32-tuples.

Comment: Thanks. This was the only thing that worked for me. `sequenceOf both (IO a,IO b)` failed when the types of `a` and `b` were different.