# sequence from a specific field of a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples, sequence, monads

I have a tuple with a `Maybe Int` in the second place. If this value is nothing, then the entire tuple is useless and should be discarded. I'd like to sequence over the tuple to bring the Maybe context out of the second place to envelop the entire tuple.

The signature of what I'm looking to do might be:

```
Monad m => (a, mb) -> m(a, b)
```

but I was unable to find anything similar on Hoogle.

I've read [Haskell -- Is there a monad sequence function for tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913656/haskell-is-there-a-monad-sequence-function-for-tuples), but it does not address the need.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Sequence.html can only handle the case where the tuples are all wrapped in monad. I.e., `Monad m => (ma, mb) -> m(a, b)`.

I can achieve this with a lambda function that tests the second element of the tuple and produces the appropriate response, but I'm wondering if there's an existing tool that does the job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just ordinary `sequence` on pairs.  The traversable is `(,) a`, and the second element is the thing that gets traversed.

```
ghci> sequence ('a', Just 3)
Just ('a',3)
ghci> sequence ('a', Nothing)
Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've pointed out, you can do it yourself for `Maybe`.

```
sequenceMaybe :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
sequenceMaybe (_, Nothing) = Nothing
sequenceMaybe (a, Just b) = Just (a, b)
```

And, in fact, we can generalize this to arbitrary monads pretty easily. In fact, we don't even need `Monad`; we just need `Functor`.

```
sequenceTuple :: Functor f => (a, f b) -> f (a, b)
sequenceTuple (a, fb) = fmap ((,) a) fb
```

If you really want a library function, then you've already found it: [`SequenceT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Sequence.html). You have a `(a, m b)`, and `SequenceT` wants a `(m a, m b)`. It's trivial to wrap values which are *not* monadic in monadic context: that's what `return` does (or `pure`, for `Applicative`).

```
sequenceTuple' :: Applicative f => (a, f b) -> f (a, b)
sequenceTuple' (a, fb) = sequenceT (pure a, fb)
```

But that's bringing a nuclear warhead to a knife fight. The `sequenceTuple` is going to be quick and to-the-point. And it works on arbitrary `Functor` instances.